# extra space (empty rows) at top of webpages

Tags: html, css

I'm a real novice... using a simple page layout on the website:

www.nohospitaldowntown.com

You'll see that each page has extra, "empty space" (rows?), which I'd like to eliminate- or understand how to control. You can see the "extra space" between the top menu and the image that follows after the "extra space". The space seems to be created by, or in the vicinity, of the code:

However, I'm only guessing that this 'div' is the culprit.

My goal is to eliminate this "extra space" on each page.

Thanks and I hope I've correctly explained my situation-
Brett

Answer (score 2):

You have given a margin-top of 177px to the .container.  That is causing the space. Decrease the number of pixels and you should have the look you want.

Comment: May I also suggest that you wrap your top navigation in a div with a class of .navigation.  That way you don't need to use <br /> which is bad form.  Instead you can create the space above the navigation with your css by adding a margin at the top (similar to what you're doing right now with .container).

Comment: Additionally, I suggest you pull the css out of the pages and into a css file, say called "my-styles.css".  Then use <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-styles.css" /> within the <head> of each page to link that stylesheet to your pages.  That way you only need to write the styles for things like nav and container one time and it will apply to any page you add the <link> to.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the inline css in your home page containing '.container'.  The 'margin-top' property is currently set to 177px.  Change this to a smaller value, say 77px.  You will have to do this for each page off your menu since each page has it's own inline css.